# Call a class method from another class which is in a list in that class (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two classes like this:

```
Public Class Class1 : Inherits Control
    Public Items As New List(Of Class2)
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Private txt as String
    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return txt
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            txt = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I want to call Invalidate() method of Class1 when Text property of Class2 Changes.

Comment: As far as Class1 is concerned, Class2 is just some data.  If you want them to interact, Class2 either needs to raise an event that C1 watches, or each C2 needs an object references to C1.  Hard to tell what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to achieve and also post when possible what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is edit **class2** so that it raises an event whenever the txt property is changed. The class should now read

```
Public Class Class2
    Private txt As String
    Public Shared Event txtChanged()
    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return txt
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Dim oldTxt As String = txt
            txt = value
            If oldTxt = txt Then
                Exit Property
            Else
                RaiseEvent txtChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Note line 3 that declares a shared event and the line in your property setter that raises the event. The shared event is so that we can add a common event handler for all the subsequent instances of **class2**

Write your event handler.

```
Private Sub Class2_txtChanged()
    'add your code here to calle the invalidate method for class1
        End Sub
```

Finally, in your Form's load event add this line to link the class to the event handler:

```
AddHandler Class2.txtChanged, AddressOf Class2_txtChanged
```

In your event handler you can now call the **.Invalidate** method in your instance of **class1**

Answer (score 0):

A delegate maybe a solution:

```
public class Class1 : Control
{
    List<Class2> items = new List<Class2>();

    public void Method1()
    {
        Action invalidate = delegate() { this.Invalidate(); };
        items.Add(new Class2(invalidate));

        items[0].Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //At this line call invalidate of class1
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    private string _text;
    private Action  _class1_invalidate;

    public Class2(Action c1_invalidate)
    {
        this._class1_invalidate = c1_invalidate;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set 
        { 
            _text = value; 
            this._class1_invalidate();
        }
    }   
}
```